# How to call a class method from the button in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a class method from a button's onclick event handler, but I'm encountering an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Account.add is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

Here's my code:

```js
class Account {
  #count;
  constructor(name, count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.#count = count;
  }  
  add() {
    return this.#count + 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Something about ...</h1>
<div>
    <h1 id='sth'>            
        Something
    </h1>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="Account.add()">Click me</button>
```

I'm trying to call the add method of the Account class directly from the button's onclick attribute. How can I correctly call a class method in this context without encountering the TypeError?

Comment: You need to instanciate your class : `const account = new Account(); account.add()`

Comment: You either need to create a new instance of the class or use static methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of doing that. One is the static method and the second is initializing your class. Since you have a constructor setting some vars which are being used in add(), you need to initialize the class before calling its methods.

```js
class Account {
  #count;
  constructor(name, count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.#count = count;
  }  
  add() {
    return this.#count + 1;
  }
}

const account = new Account(); // <----- Initialize class
```

```html
<h1>Something about ...</h1>
<div>
    <h1 id='sth'>            
        Something
    </h1>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="account.add()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it if it is an static method, like this:

```js
class Account {
  #count;
  constructor(name, count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.#count = count;
  }  
  static add() {
    return this.#count + 1;
  }
}
// but now you will get different error since static methods have different `this`
```

if it is not static method you need to initialize object on whom that method will be called.
For example:

```js
class Account {
  #count;
  constructor(name, count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.#count = count;
  }  
  add() {
    return this.#count + 1;
  }
}

const newAcc = new Account("name", 0);
```

And then from your template you can do:

```js
<body>
  <h1>Something about ...</h1>
  <div>
      <h1 id='sth'>            
          Something
      </h1>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="acc.add()">Click me</button>
</body>
```